# How to Wire an Exhaust Fan/Light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, exhaust-fan

The exhaust fan/light I have has black, white, green, and blue wires. The house wires are black, white, ground, and red.

Comment: Blue and black are for the light and the fan. If you've got one switch, then they mate with the house's black wire. The red house wire is odd. You should take a picture of the switch box's wiring and the house wiring in the ceiling box.

Comment: Do you have one switch for the light and one switch for the fan? Or are they both on the same switch? My first guess is that the black house wire is the hot conductor for a light or fan and the red house wire is the hot conductor for a fan or light.

Comment: The red house wire is not odd. It's the standard color of the 3rd conductor in /3 cable, which is utterly common for both post NEC2011 switch loops and fan/light wiring with two switches, one switching black and one switching red. But other than green to ground we still need pictures to offer useful advice that isn't based on assumptions that might be incorrect. Please [edit] to add those.